# Selenium webdriver - Java - How to get code value from tr element?

Tags: selenium, xpath, webdriver

I would like to get td code value based on td text value. Please refer the attached image. Kindly help!!

[Copy Tag name](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E8F2Z.png)

Below code didn't work

```
      WebElement test1 = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='table table-striped-admin']//tr//td[contains(text(),'"+tag_name+"')]//td//code"));
                                                                test1.getText();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
WebElement test1 =driver.findElement(By.xpath("//table[@class='table table-striped-admin']//tr[contains(td[1],'Tag Name 1')]/td/code"));

test1.getText();
```

???